# Setting the environment variables at EC2 for a RoR app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, heroku, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a Rails app which I want to deploy to EC2 instance. I know how to set the environment variables at Heroku. But how to do that at AWS EC2? I need that because I have to connect to MongoDb and mongoid.yml looks like the following:

```
production:
  host: <%= ENV['MONGOID_HOST'] %>
  port: <%= ENV['MONGOID_PORT'] %>
  username: <%= ENV['MONGOID_USERNAME'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['MONGOID_PASSWORD'] %>
  database: <%= ENV['MONGOID_DATABASE'] %>
  logger: false
```

I didn't find that in google.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using Capistrano to deploy your app? In that case, I suggest adding `figaro` gem into your application, and then you can create an `application.yml` file inside shared/config/ folder and link it with `current` directory in your app.

Read more here: http://railsguides.net/how-to-define-environment-variables-in-rails/

Comment: I'm still trying to choose between capistrano and passenger. I guess there must be another, a simpler way without using figaro gem.

Comment: Yeah, you can just add your environment variables to .bashrc and they would be available in your Rails application

Comment: Sure? `<%= ENV['MONGOID_HOST'] %>` has nothing to do with a Linux environment variables.

Comment: Yes, but Passenger or Rails app will automatically load these environment variables so they would be available in your app. You can try running `rails console` in your local machine and type `ENV`, you would see your Linux environment variables in the output